# How do I require a login view in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have these files in this folder structure:

-application 
--view 
---Login.js 
---Viewport.js 
--app.js 
-extjs 
-index.html

**Login.js**

> ```
> Ext.define('BBP.view.Login', {
> extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
> alias: 'widget.Login',
>
> initComponent: function() {
>    var me = this;
>
>    Ext.applyIf(me, {
>        items: [
>            {
>                xtype: 'form',
>                height: 140,
>                width: 280,
>                resizable: false,
>                bodyPadding: 14,
>                title: 'Login',
>                url: 'user/login',
>                items: [
>                    {
>                        xtype: 'textfield',
>                        width: 240,
>                        fieldLabel: 'Username',
>                        name: 'Username'
>                    },
>                    {
>                        xtype: 'textfield',
>                        width: 240,
>                        fieldLabel: 'Password',
>                        name: 'Password'
>                    },
>                    {
>                        xtype: 'button',
>                        margin: '6 0 0 104',
>                        padding: '2 20 2 20',
>                        width: 136,
>                        resizable: false,
>                        text: 'Login'
>                    }
>                ]
>            }
>        ]
>    });
> }
>
> });
> ```

**Viewport.js:**

> ```
> Ext.define('BBP.view.Viewport', {
> extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
> layout: 'fit',
>
> items:[{
>      xtype:'panel',
>      title:'Brievenbusprofiel',
>      items:[{
>              xtype: 'Login'
>      }]
> }],
>
> initComponent: function() {
>    var me = this;
>
>    me.callParent(arguments);
> }
>
> });
> ```

**app.js**

> ```
> Ext.Loader.setConfig({
> enabled: true
> });
>
> Ext.application({
> name: 'BBP',
> appFolder: 'app',
> autoCreateViewport: true,
> views: [
>     'Login'
> ],
> launch: function() {}
> });
> ```

this only shows me the panel and not my login form.

I tried to fix this by adding:

> ```
> requires:['app.view.Login'],
> ```

To my viewport.js code. But then nothing appears on screen.

How can I load my Login view into my viewport?

Comment: Have you tried `requires:['BBP.view.Login']`?

Comment: I would reconsider your approach. By baking the login window (which is an odd class to extend, considering how you're using it) into the items config of the Viewport, you'll basically require that view to display every time the Viewport is rendered. But what if the user is already logged in? I would suggest delaying the creation of the Viewport until after you've done the necessary login checks...if the user isn't logged in, display the login window, and then create the viewport once login is successful. If the user is already logged in, just create the viewport and don't mess with the login.

Comment: I did try that, not the solution. I think I'll reconsider the approach of the application. I've got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The correct way of adding login file to viewport is **requires: ['Bpp.view.Login']** not **requires: ['app.view.Login']**.

2.Required to add me.callParent() method to **login** also

3.In viewport before CallParent method need to add **Ext.create('Bpp.view.Login').show()** method.

Answer (score -1):

add one config in your Login.js like below.

```
 xtype: 'Login'
```

it will work for you.

Comment: `alias: widget.foo` does exactly the same thing.